# What makes an object absorbing angular momentum while colliding with another object?

Tags: angular-momentum, angular-velocity

There is a line of spinning top toys in Japan called Beyblades. So, there is a 'stadium' (surface) along which the Beyblades spin around after being set to spin at high RPMs by the players, and the first Beyblade to stop spinning is said to be the winner.

Out of all the Beyblades, there was this one particular Beyblade that always caught my attention. It is known as Meteo L Drago. What's special about this Beyblade is that it somehow gains angular momentum every time it collides... what exactly is the physics of this?

[image]

How can object be set up such that it gains angular momentum everytime? I know of angular momentum conservation but I've never understood how the angular momentum can be transfered to one particular object in a collision.

[Visual demonstration of this phenomena](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ufOgv8dDxI&ab_channel=RumyReviews)

Comment: L Drago always spins in the opposite direction. Like if all other Beyblades spins clockwise, it spins counterclockwise. It's just the way it's designed.

Comment: That is sort of weird, does a counterclockwise spinning object always absorb spin from a clockwise spinning object?

Comment: No there are other factors. If a counterclockwise spinning beyblade comes in contact with a clockwise spinning beyblade, then both their tangential velocities point in the same direction. So one of them gains momentum in the tangential direction and one of them loses momentum. Compare that to two clockwise beyblades approaching. Both their tangential velocity is opposite and both lose momentum in the tangential direction.

Comment: Now in a counterclockwise vs. clockwise collision, you'd expect momentum transfer from the higher spinning bey to the lower spinning one. But if they're at relatively the same speed, those rubber "claws" of L drago come into play. They help spin stealing but the effect  reduces as they wear down due to overuse.

Comment: ", then both their tangential velocities point in the same direction." .. how? once in clock wise and one is counter so must be opposite.

Comment: "n, you'd expect momentum transfer from the higher spinning bey to the lower spinning one. " How did you arrive at the idea that angular momentum always goes from high spin to low spin

Comment: "once in clock wise and one is counter so must be opposite" Only if you put one on top of the other. When they're side by side, it's not. I suggest you draw a top side view and see for yourself. I wasn't talking about angular momentum transfer there. I was taking about their tangential linear momentum. Like in a collision between something with higher momentum with something with lower momentum, there is a momentum transfer from high to low unless the collision is very ineslastic

Comment: Ok yeah I see what you meant by the opposite directions now but I'm not really sure about the direction of momentum transfer